# Can't write to file while using command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, bufferedwriter

I can write to the file when I don't put a command line argument but whenever I do put a command line argument it doesn't write. Even if I'm not even using the command line argument.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Test {

    public Test () throws IOException {

        String content = "writing...";

        File file = new File("sample.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: try flushing the stream? `bw.flush()`. Also, change the constructor throwing an exception to a try {} catch{} so we can see whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `flush` the data from the `RAM` to the `HDD|SSD` so:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
      // Write the data to the memory
      bw.write(content);
      // You need to flush the data
      bw.flush();
      // Close the BufferedWriter
      bw.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to write the data on the file", ex);
}
```

Comment: oh it was flushing the stream, I didn't post because I wasn't sure but I'm glad you did.

Comment: @ Ashwin Gupta ;) . . .